# NLog layout ignoring windows identity attributes

Tags: .net, nlog

I have the following windows identity layout parameter:

```
${windows-identity:userName=True:domain=False}
```

The problem is the attribute 'domain=False' is being ignored, the output is still showing the domain, e.g:

FM\richeso

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

.Net 4.0 application using the latest NLog nuGet packages.

Comment: Are you sure that you have saved your config, and restarted your application or auto-reload is turned on? Because your config should work... maybe you can try to turn on the nlog internal logging.

Comment: I just copy / pasted that. It works as expected: No domain.

Comment: The app was not picking up the modified config correctly, sorted it now, thanks